# Perturbation expansion Q. who get the best answer?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

know $y''+(1+f(x)\epsilon)y=0$ with $y(0)=1$ and $y(\pi)=0$
find perturbation expansion. 
How can I find the expansion after I get the y(x)?
Many thanks

Comment: Made a few minor edits.  Added the differential equations tag.

Answer (score 1):

The problem does not have a solution. This assertion is inspired by @Dylan's sharp observation below.

Suppose the contrary. The equation has to hold at $\epsilon=0$. We then have 
$$y''+y =0,\quad y(0)=1,\ y(\pi)=0.$$
Then $y(x)=a\cos(x)+b\sin(x)$ for some constant $(a,b)$. But $y(0)=a=1$ and $y(\pi)=-a=0$, a contradiction.

---

Here is the general solution and condition for the existence of a solution. This is

Suppose the boundary is at $(x_1,x_2)$ and $y(x_1)=\alpha_1$, $y(x_2)=\alpha_2$.

At $\epsilon=0$, we should have 
$$y''+y =0,\quad y(x_1)=\alpha_1,\ y(x_2)=\alpha_2.$$
$$y(x)=a\cos(x)+b\sin(x)$$
for some constant $(a,b)$. We should have
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
\cos(x_1) & \sin(x_1) \\
\cos(x_2) & \sin(x_2) 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
a \\ b\end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
\alpha_1 \\ \alpha_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
For the above linear algebra system to have solution for arbitrary $(\alpha_1, \alpha_2)$, $\tan(x_1)\neq\tan(x_2)$.

(to be continued)

---

The following is the general solution for the non-degenerate conditions prescribed above.

Let $y = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\epsilon^n y_n$, where $y_0(x_1)=\alpha_1,\,y_0(x_2)=\alpha_2$ and $y_n(x_1)=y_n(x_2)=0,\ \forall n\in\mathbf N$. Substitute it into the original equation. We have
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \epsilon^{n+1} (y_{n+1}''+ y_{n+1}+ f(x)y_n)=0.$$
Setting the coefficients of $\epsilon^{n+1}$ to zero, or
\begin{align}
y_0''+y_0&=0,\quad y_0(x_1)=\alpha_1,\ y_0(x_2)=\alpha_2,\\
y_n''+y_n+ f(x)y_{n-1}&=0,\quad y_n(x_1)=y_n(x_2)=0,\quad \forall n\in\mathbf N.
\end{align}
You have the recursive equations to solve for $y$. The first boundary value problem is solved by a $\cos$ function. The second boundary value problem can be solved by many techniques, such as variational method, Fourier series expansion, e.t.c.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, $y_n(0)=1$ but not $y_n(0)=0$, this might have a big efffect on solving the equation. Could you give me precise work?

Comment: @chowchow: I have added the needed boundary conditions and pointed out the way to solve all the equations. Check it out. If you are satisfied with my answer, please accept it.

Comment: The first BVP does not have a solution, since $\cos (\pi) =-1$

Comment: @Dylan: You are absolutely right. The boundary situates right at a pair of points where the matrix that determines it is degenerate. The problem is a tricky one. I am editing my answer.